# Extract r^2 from multiple models in plyr

Tags: r, plyr, perfect-square

I am hoping to efficiently combine my regressions using plyr functions. I have data frames with monthly data for multiple years in format `yDDDD` (so `y2014`, `y2013`, etc.)

Right now, I have the below code for one of those dfs, `y2014`. I am running the regressions by month, as desired within each year.

```
modelsm2= by(y2014,y2014$Date,function(x) lm(y~,data=x))
summarym2=lapply(modelsm2,summary)
coefficientsm2=lapply(modelsm2,coef)
coefsm2v2=ldply(modelsm2,coef) #to get the coefficients into an exportable df
```

I have several things I'd like to do and I would really appreciate your help!

A. Extract the `r^2` for each model. I know that for one model, you can do `summary(model)$r.squared` to get it, but I have not had luck with my construct.

B. Apply the same methodology in a loop-type structure to get the models to run for all of my data frames (`y2013` and backwards)

C. Get the summary into an easily exportable (to Excel) format --> the `ldply` function does not work for the summaries.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You need to subset out the `r.squared` values from your summaries:

```
lapply(summarym2,"[[","r.squared")
```

B. Put all your data into a list, and put another `lapply` around it, eg:

```
lapply(list(y2014,y2013,y2012), function(dat)
                                   by(dat,dat$Date, function(x) lm(y~.,data=x))
      )
```

You will then have a list of lists so for instance to extract the summaries, you would use:

```
lapply(lmlist,lapply,summary)
```

C. `summary` returns a fairly complex data structure that cannot be coerced into a data.frame. The result you see is a consequence of the `print` method for it. You can use `capture.output` to get a charactor vector of each line of the output that you may use to write to a file.

Comment: Thank you, A works great and understood on C. For B, however, can you please elaborate? How do I avoid atomic vector problems within my by function that's in the lapply: the below does not work for me: models=lapply(dflist,by(dflist[],dflist[,1],function(x)lm(y~,data=x)))

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help. Helped a lot with my beginner understanding of the plyr commands.